# Using multiple forms on the same page in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, registration, login-control

I have **login** and **signup** forms on a single asp.net page (like facebook landing page) and I want to fire submit both forms on the page independently from each other. While `a page can have only one server-side form tag`, I can't do it.

İs this a simple way to do that?

I used *panel*, *validationgroup*, *requiredformvalidation*, *webusercontrol*, *etc*. However, it didn't work.

UPDATE:

What am I trying to do that is;

when I click **LOGIN** button as showed on the picture here, it warns me to fill the **REGISTER** form textbox controls. I just want to be able to click both **REGISTER** and **LOGIN** buttons individual or indipendent.

[image: Login / Register Page Example]

Comment: are you using MVC ?

Comment: No, I heard that there is an easy way to do it on MVC, but I don't have it.

Comment: in MVC it is easy .

Comment: read this if it answer your question please mark my answer . it tells you have to deal with multiple forms in asp.net webpage  .

Comment: http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/

Comment: Thank you Yashveer Singh but that is not a solution for me.

Comment: You can use Html forms to do that. When you use form with runat="server" in asp.net, only one server-side form tag you can use as you said.

Comment: I think, there will be no other chance to use html forms.

Comment: Please include your aspx markup for the forms. Hard to tell what is going on without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Please read this link it tells you how to work with multiple forms inside a page hope it helps .
```

http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple way. You can send the values you need via AJAX. You will need a WebMethod to handle it and Javascript code to collect it. Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myform" data-formid="login">
    <input type="text" data-name="username">
    <input type="password" data-name="password"
    <span class="submit"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var func = $(this).parent().data("formid");
        var valueItems = $(this).siblings(["data-name"]);
        var data = {};
        valueItems.each(function() {
            data[$(this).data("name")] = $(this).val();
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: yoururl,
            data: data
            method: "POST"
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //Response
        });
    });
});
```

And finally you will need an .svc file server-side and implement the login `WebMethod` correctly. Example:

```
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
    Public Function ConvertTemperature(ByVal dFahrenheit As Double) _
                                       As Double
        ConvertTemperature = ((dFahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9
    End Function
End Class
```

Taken from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx).